# рекурсивная функция, подсчет элементов в массиве

Tags: c, массивы, рекурсия

Мне необходимо подсчитать сумму первой и четвертой строки в массиве, однако происходит какая-то проблема в функции `sumArray` (есть подозрения на `if(i<n)` и `if(i<j)`). Cумма `s` сначала находится верно, а затем идет на уменьшение и превращается в 1. Не знаю, как исправить, надеюсь на вашу помощь. 
p.s. на первые две функции не смотрите, они страшные[image: введите сюда описание изображения].

```
#include<stdio.h
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void inputMatrix(int n, int i, int j, int a[][10]) {
  if (i < n)
    if (j < n)
      printf("(%i,%i)= ", i, j), scanf("%i", & a[i][j]), inputMatrix(n, i, j + 1, a);
    else j = 0, inputMatrix(n, i + 1, j, a);
}
void OutputMatrix(int n, int i, int j, int a[][10]) {
  if (i < n)
    if (j < n)
      printf("%5i", a[i][j]), OutputMatrix(n, i, j + 1, a);
    else {
      puts(" ");
      OutputMatrix(n, i + 1, 0, a);
    }
}

int sumM(int n, int i, int j, int a[][10], int s) {
  if (i < n) {
    if (j < n) {
      {
        if (i == 0 || i == 3) {
          s += a[i][j];
          sumM(n, i, j + 1, a, s);
        } else j = 0;
        sumM(n, i + 1, j, a, s);
      }
    }

  }
  if (i == n - 1) {
    printf("\n%i", s);

  }
  return s;
}

int main() {
  int c[10][10], s;
  float medium;
  inputMatrix(4, 0, 0, c);
  OutputMatrix(4, 0, 0, c);
  s = sumM(4, 0, 0, c, 0);
  printf("\nsum= %i", s);
  puts("\n");
  system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Как минимум вы передаете `s` по значению, так что все изменения `s` внутри функции просто оказываются потерянными...

Comment: мне не важны остальные значения, а только лишь конечное, которое по идее должно быть 32 (если обратиться к тем данным, что я ввел на фото), а оно выходит в начале и идет на уменьшение

Comment: Ну как мне вам объяснить? Не важно - значит не важно... значит, и так сойдет. Выкиньте рекурсивные вызовы - все равно *кроме вывода* они *ничего не делают*. И будет у вас только один правильный выод :) Вы понимаете это или опять "не важно"? Что `sumM(n, i + 1, j, a, s);` ничего не считает, только выводит  сумму куска? Рекурсии у вас **НЕТ**.